# Changes in pandas dataframe appearance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, I need to change the look and feel of that dataframe to send that dataframe over email. I need to change the color of individual rows needs to make some rows bold in between the  dataframe.

Input DF:-

```html
Country         
  2019 2018  2019 2018  Difference Difference%
 Country/INR Header_1   Header_2    
0 Netherlands 3,661 2,875  3,661 2,875  786 30.00%
1 Croatia 396 279  396 279  117 30.00%
2 Belgium 2,247 1,890  2,247 1,890  357 30.00%
3  2019 2018  2019 2018  Difference Difference%
4 Country/INR Header_1   Header_2    
5 Netherlands 3,661 2,875  3,661 2,875  786 30.00%
6 Croatia 396 279  396 279  117 30.00%
7 Belgium 2,247 1,890  2,247 1,890  357 30.00%
```

[image]

Output needed :-

```html
Country Wise Data         
  2019 2018  2019 2018  Difference Difference%
 Country/INR Header_1   Header_2   Header_3 
0 Netherlands 3,661 2,875  3,661 2,875  786 30.00%
1 Croatia 396 279  396 279  117 30.00%
2 Belgium 2,247 1,890  2,247 1,890  357 30.00%
3  2019 2018  2019 2018  Difference Difference%
4 Country/INR Header_3   Header_4   Header_5 
5 Netherlands 3,661 2,875  3,661 2,875  786 30.00%
6 Croatia 396 279  396 279  117 30.00%
7 Belgium 2,247 1,890  2,247 1,890  357 30.00%
```

[image]

If someone have some HTML changes done with the dataframes. Please share with me. (How to use df.to_html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the structure of your data frame, however, applying a conditional styling is possible in pandas through [`pd.DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) feature.

I used a subset of you `DataFrame` to illustrate how to apply bold font on specific cells.

Assuming `df` looks like this:

```
    2019    2018
0   Country/INR Header_1
1   Netherlands 3,661
2   Croatia 396
3   Belgium 2,247
```

```
newDf = (df
         .style # Access the styling methods for a DataFrame
          .applymap(lambda x: 'font-weight : bold', # Change the font-weight to bold
                    subset=pd.IndexSlice[2:2, ['2019']])) # return a pd Styler object)

newDf.render() # returns formatted HTML
```

```html
<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row2_col0 {
            font-weight :  bold;
            font-weight :  bold;
        }</style><table id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122" ><thead>    <tr>        <th class="blank level0" ></th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >2019</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >2018</th>    </tr></thead><tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >Country/INR</td>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >Header_1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >Netherlands</td>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >3,661</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >Croatia</td>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >396</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122level0_row3" class="row_heading level0 row3" >3</th>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row3_col0" class="data row3 col0" >Belgium</td>
                        <td id="T_57b07620_cc86_11e9_82f9_acde48001122row3_col1" class="data row3 col1" >2,247</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hey @iDrwish the 1st image I have posted in my Q is my dataframe and 2nd image is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Since you are only add bold as a style, my answer provides just that. You can expand the index or even implement functions to get conditional dynamic styling.